# Converting txt file with words into equal-sized matrices in Python

Tags: python, arrays, file, matrix

I have a .txt file (pic attached) that for each time step, has a 25 x 19 matrix. I am trying to create a 3D matrix so that I can open the first matrix which will have 25 rows and 19 columns. Essentially, I want to read the entire file besides the lines with Time : [] and cleave the entire file into 50 matrices, each with 25 rows and 19 columns.

I am more familiar with doing this in MATLAB, so any help would be appreciated! Please let me know if you have any questions.

picture of how my text file looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can open a file and read it line by line by using a for loop like so:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

Then, you know that the lines you are interested in do not start with the word `Time` so you can test for that:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # skip lines that start with time and empty lines
        if line.startswith('Time') or len(line) == 0:
            continue
```

Now, we want to create our matrix.  Since you seem to have a more data-science-oriented problem, I am going to strongly recommend you use `numpy`.  I am going to create a list of numpy matrices each of which will be 25 x 19.  Here's how this would work:

```
import numpy as np    

# create our list of matrices
matrices = []

# which row we are in as we generate our matrix
line_pos = 0

# loop through each line in the file
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # know `Time` always begins a new block so we use that to
        # push a new matrix to our list
        if line.startswith('Time'):
            matrices.append(np.zeroes((25, 19)))
            line_pos = 0
            continue
        elif len(line) == 0:
            continue

        # add a new row to the last (top) matrix;
        # basically, split the line by tabs (which appear to be between each element)
        # and then apply a function that first strips away any additional whitespace
        # and then converts the elements to floats
        matrices[-1][line_pos] = list(map(lambda x: float(x.strip()), line.split('\t')))

        # move to insert on next line
        line_pos += 1
```

Hopefully, this is helpful for you.  I don't have a copy of your original data so I can't test if this works, but if it doesn't it should at least give you a place to start from.  I am aware the one-liner at the end is a bit complicated, but you said you are a Matlab guy so I assume applying functions to sets of elements is not unfamiliar to you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Do I need to import another library besides numpy? Just wondering because I got an error saying "TypeError: Cannot interpret '19' as a data type" and I wasn't sure if it was syntactical or something else

Comment: Sorry.  I made a typo in my response: the call should be `np.zeroes((25, 19))`.  I corrected my code to reflect this.